# How do I make a python bot with selenium that checks when a new message has arrived from a Telegram channel?

Tags: python, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I should start off mentioning I am pretty new to python and selenium, so I don't really know much about either of them.

### what I am trying to do:

- Check every second if a telegram channel I follow has sent out a new message. I have telegram web opened on a browser opened with custom flags so that I don't need to log in with telegram every single time.

---

So far what I did is see the class that has all the message's text inside of it
`im_message_text`, and get the last of them in the list.

### Source Code

**NOTE** The "strong" tag is simply where the title is stored in side the text message, which is what i'm using to compare everything:

```
    def getItemsInfo1(self):
    try:
        iteminfo1 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 4).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'im_message_text')))
        list3 = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("im_message_text")
        list33 = list3[-1]
        list4 = list33.find_element_by_tag_name("strong")
        list4txt = list4.text
        return list4txt

    except:
        print("Nothing is found")
```

What I do from here is I make another identical code which has a `time.sleep(1)` at the start to give the message time to appear, and i compare the 2 using the following while loop:

```
        while Main.getItemsInfo1() == Main.getItemsInfo2(): 
        print("No new messages. Try number ", count)
        print(Main.getItemsInfo1(), Main.getItemsInfo2())
        count += 1
```

So far, whilst as soon as there is a new message the code output highlights that the 2 methods have different text, it still does not end the while loop and it continues to say that there aren't any new messages.

Does anyone know how to help?

Comment: what is getITemsInfo2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while Main.getItemsInfo1() == Main.getItemsInfo2():  
print("No new messages. Try number ", count)
print(Main.getItemsInfo1(), Main.getItemsInfo2())
count += 1
```

When you call getItemsInfo1() you are calling the method again , so there is no guarantee that the value is get in print statement is same as what is there in while so use something like:

```
info1= Main.getItemsInfo1()
info2= Main.getItemsInfo2()
while  info == Info2:  
   print("No new messages. Try number ", count)
   info1= Main.getItemsInfo1()
   info2= Main.getItemsInfo2()
   print(info1,info2)
   count += 1
```

The above code will make sure you are having same value, as you are storing the value to a variable and then validating it .

Comment: I just tried it and It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use telegram web or selenuim either, let's make it much more easier:
‍

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient(PHONE_NUMBER, API_ID, API_HASH)

@client.on(events.NewMessage("chanel name"))
def new_message_listener(event):
    new_message = event.message.message
    media_status = event.message.media
    ## DO what you like with new_messsage
```

Just remember to change the variables in the `TelegramClient`, You can receive API_ID, API_HASH from Telegram website.

They should be like this:

```
api_id = 1027347
api_hash = "c0e2cfefac982659a52da625b81e2a99"
```